# declared variable += and a new variable not containing last data of the previous variable

Tags: php, variables

### **Example**:

```
$variable = someCode;

$variable .= someMoreCode;

$variable .= someMoreMoreCode;
```

I want to make a `$variable2` containing only `someMoreMoreCode;`

---

**NOTES:**

1) Whitout rewritting the `someMoreMoreCode;` part.

2) Variables are in a function, so I can't just declare a `$variable2`   over the code part that interests me.

---

> Q: How can I achieve this ?

Comment: for those with a similar problem, I declared the new variable for the 3rd part of the code. then += the old one with the new and at the end of the function I returned both variables with an IF statement ( in my case ) respectively for each case I needed ( since I needed both variables )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable2=someMoreMoreCode;
return $variable2; //because it's in a function.
```

If I have interpreted well your question, this is the answer.
If not, please try to make an example and share some code.

Comment: Even though it was a bit difficult to change all the rest `$variable` to the next parts of the code. It worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking, but wouldn't `$variable2 = $variable` work ?

Comment: Then `$variable2` would include the other parts of the code too. I only want it to contain the 3rd part of the code.

Comment: Why don't you first add the value you want insider the second variable and the add the second variable to the first one ? 

`$variable = someCode;
$variable .= someMoreCode;
$variable2 = someMoreMoreCode;
$variable .= $variable2`

This way you still have `someMoreMoreCode` only written once